# Assistance with optimizing a SQL table join on an Address History table

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to figure out a quicker/more elegant way to get the data I need in a join for a SQL Report out of JDE.

I have two tables with the following data structure:

[image: Table Data]

The ADDY table is an Address history table and every time an address change is made it writes a new line with a new RecentDate value of the day the change is made.  I need to be able to pull the ADD1 value for  the most recent RecentDate value before the G/L Date of the SO table for the given Invoice #.  Also if it has a blank RecentDate it writes as 0. So what I would expect to return is as follows:

[image: Report Output]

I was able to get it work with the following SQL but it is not a quick running query and I am sure there is something quicker and more streamlined but I cannot figure it out:

```
LEFT JOIN
(
   SELECT address.ALAN8,
          case WHEN address.ALEFTB = '0' 
                        THEN cast(DATEADD(DAY,(address.ALEFTB%1000), DATEADD(YEAR,(address.ALEFTB/1000),'1910-01-01')) AS DATE)
                    ELSE cast(DATEADD(DAY,(address.ALEFTB%1000)-1, DATEADD(YEAR,(address.ALEFTB/1000),'1900-01-01')) AS DATE)
               END AS RecentDate,
           address.ALADD1 AS ALADD1,
           address.ALCTY1 AS ALCTY1,
           address.ALADDS AS ALADDS,
           address.ALADDZ AS ALADDZ
    FROM ODS.PRODDTA.F0116 AS ADDRESS
) AS ADDY
    ON so.ShipTo = addy.ALAN8
        AND addy.RecentDate = (SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN add2.ALEFTB = '0' 
                                            THEN cast(DATEADD(DAY,(add2.ALEFTB%1000), DATEADD(YEAR,(add2.ALEFTB/1000),'1910-01-01')) AS DATE)
                                                ELSE cast(DATEADD(DAY,(add2.ALEFTB%1000)-1, DATEADD(YEAR,(add2.ALEFTB/1000),'1900-01-01')) AS DATE)
                                            END) 
                                FROM ODS.PRODDTA.F0116 AS ADD2 
                                WHERE ADD2.ALAN8 =  addy.ALAN8
                                    AND so.GLDate >= CASE WHEN add2.ALEFTB = '0' 
                                            THEN cast(DATEADD(DAY,(add2.ALEFTB%1000), DATEADD(YEAR,(add2.ALEFTB/1000),'1910-01-01')) AS DATE)
                                                ELSE cast(DATEADD(DAY,(add2.ALEFTB%1000)-1, DATEADD(YEAR,(add2.ALEFTB/1000),'1900-01-01')) AS DATE)
                                            END)
```

Comment: What's the database?

Comment: Your database structure is not very efficient. I would start by adding a foreign key from CUIDO to ADDY, to persist which address was used for each order, instead of computing it at runtime on every query. Worst of all, a badly written query could pick the wrong one.

Comment: Database is Oracle

Comment: Which version of Oracle?  Oracle, as of 19c, doesn't support: `FROM ODS.PRODDTA.F0116 AS ADDRESS` ... this use of the `AS` keyword in the `FROM` clause.

Comment: Tough to review without at least a complete query, the schema (create table, plus constraints / indexes), some data and the explain plan.

Comment: DATEADD(DAY) is a SQL Server function.